# New Files App on iPhone Showing 0 Files

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

With the old iCloud App on my iPhone SE, I could always see my Macbook's Desktop and Documents folder.
That is no longer the case with the new Files App!  It will show the amount of free space available, but no files.
The size matches what is actually shown in [iCloud](http://icloud.com).

In the Files App, it always shows *0* files.  My wife can still see all of the files from my MacBook's Desktop and Documents folder on her iPad (same iCloud account). However, I cannot.

I can create a new file/folder on my MacBook and it is viewable immediately on the iPad but not my iPhone.

What could be causing this and how would I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to enable iCloud Drive in order to showcase the iCloud Drive files and folders.

> On your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch
>
> 1. Go to Settings > [your name].
> 2. Tap iCloud.
> 3. Swipe to turn on iCloud Drive.
>
> You can find your iCloud Drive files in the Files app.
>
> After you set up iCloud Drive, any documents that you've already
>   stored in iCloud are automatically moved to iCloud Drive. Your iPhone,
>   iPad, iPod touch, and iCloud.com keep your files in the Files app in
>   addition to the Pages, Numbers, and Keynote apps. If you don't see
>   your files in these apps, they might be on a device that doesn't have
>   iCloud Drive turned on (***or under a different Apple ID***).

**Set up iCloud Drive** - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204025

Comment: Thank you for your response. All that you suggested was already preformed long ago and worked for months.  My files just simply disappeared but were clearly available from our iPad as mentioned in my earlier post.  Yesterday I downloaded the newest IOS update which came out yesterday, and the next time I looked for my files (with the Files App) they were all there just like they had been in the past.  You got me... did the IOS update fix it (due to a bug in an earlier IOS version) or something else?  Anyway I am back to normal after searching the web for answers for weeks!!!!  Thanks again!!

Comment: Did you have the latest version(11.2.1) before you install iOS 11.2.2?

Comment: It's quite possible that it was iOS related. Just keep your eyes on it and see if the issue returns.